# If statement is not working correctly discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically I am making a kicking system in for a discord bot where the user will input .k @user and it will kick that user. I have a global variable called counter that is supposed to count how many relations are in the message in order for the user to be kicked. For testing purposes, I have set that if there is one reaction it should kick the person.

```
@client.command(aliases=['k'])
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member):
guild = ctx.message.guild
voice_state = ctx.author.voice
if voice_state is None:
    return await ctx.send('you need to be in a voice channel to use this command')
voice_state = user.voice
if voice_state is None:
    return await ctx.send(f'{user} needs to be in a voice channel to use this command')
emb = discord.Embed(title=" Vote to kick", description=f"do you want to kick: {user}?", colour=(0x3498db))
msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
global msgId
msgId = msg.id
await msg.add_reaction('✔')
if counter == 1:
    return await ctx.send('ur if statement worked!')
```

I don't know if my global variable doesn't work or my if statement. Whenever I run this the user instantly gets kicked even though the counter equals zero. (I have @client.events about that track the reactions and add to the counter)

Comment: Please fix your indentation so we can tell what's in the function.